# Azure's new Vnet integration for app services to access on-premise resources via site to site VPN

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

The app service is connected to Vnet with the new Vnet integration. The same Vnet is connect to on-premise network with site to site VPN. How to get the app service to access the resources on-premise?

Comment: This question lacks any code to show us that you've made any attempt to solve this yourself. If you've tried something, show us what you've tried, example of the expected output and what you're actually getting. If you haven't tried anything, you need to do that before posting. We can help you with your existing code, but we won't write it for you. Please read: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example and also How do I ask a good question?

Comment: The error is "..connection attempt failed..". I dont face any error when the resources in my Vnet connect back to on-premise resources though.

Note that I am using the new Vnet integration, not the point-to-site integration.

Answer (score 0):

Your exact ask is documented in the Public Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet

Once you configured the  VNET integration in Azure end, you need to configure the routes in On-Prem to connect to the App Service. Post that you will have connectivity to On-Premises. You can get your App Service IP address from VNET integration blade of your App Service. You need to configure this address in On-premises VPN device.

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: But the documentation mainly covers the point-to-site integration. I'm using the new Vnet integration to access to on-premise resources through site to site VPN. Currently, the resources in the Vnet are able to access the on-premise resources through the VPN.

Comment: The feature which you are referring is currently in Public Preview. We do not recommend it for Production workload. It does work for Express Route as per the documentation and for Site to Site, i need to test before commenting here. As a workaround, can you use the Point to Site integration ?